# Image object in windows vista (Java)

Tags: java, image, windows-vista

I am trying to add a background image to my GUI (on java).
All the commands for GUI I got from my university..

```
try {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(Background.class.getResourceAsStream("myBackground.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DrawSurface d = ... (commands from university jar)
d.drawImage(0, 0, image);
```

I **see** the background when I run it (as a jar) on Windows XP.

I **don't see** the background when I run it (the same jar) on Windows Vista (Without any exception! ), so I think it may be something with Vista settings..

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Answer

Don't use Vista.

### Less Simple Answer

More than likely, one of two things is happening in your University's code:

- The code is attempting to draw straight to a JComponent, and it is not being called correctly by the System, because of how Vista handles internal `repaint()` calls.
- Your school's code has a feature in it that is not hardware independent. Go figure.

Comment: Thanks. When I'm using File object instead of getResourceAsStream method, I see the background on vista but not on university server. Because of that I change it to getResourceAsStream. Do you know other methods that may work in both server and vista?

Comment: You could  say "don't use Vista or XP" and this would be no less true.